# ng:areq : Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

**JS:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('appModule',
              [
                'ngRoute',                
                'winjs'
              ]);

    app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.splitViewElement = document.getElementById('splitView');
    });   
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta content="IE=edge, chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    maximum- scale=1" />

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app-main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="app/device/device-main.js"></script>
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController as app">
    <div>
        <win-split-view-pane-toggle split-view="splitViewElement">
        </win-split-view-pane-toggle>
        <win-split-view id="splitView">
            <win-split-view-pane>
                SplitView Navigation Pane
                <win-split-view-command label="'Home'" 
                icon="'home'" on-invoked="goToHome()"></win-split-view-command>
                <win-split-view-command label="'Settings'" 
                icon="'settings'" on-invoked="goToSettings()">
            </win-split-view-command>
        </win-split-view-pane>
        <win-split-view-content>SplitView Content Area
        </win-split-view-content>
    </win-split-view>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Have included the "app-main.js", that contains the JS code above, Could someone please examine and let me know the reason for the above error.

Comment: you should `ng-app="appModule"`

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your app in the ng-app. Like this

```
<html ng-app="appModule">
```

Then it will work.

```
if the ngApp directive were not placed on the html element then the document would not be compiled, the AppController would not be instantiated
```

See angularjs docs for reference on this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: Ok thank you, but after adding it I get the following error:

Failed to instantiate module appModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=d...)

Comment: What is 'winjs' in the module initialization? Only Angular modules should be added on app initialization. You should not add your own js scripts into it.

Comment: Tried removing "WinJs" from the dependencies, but still the same error

Comment: Which AngularJS version you are using?

Comment: angularjs version 1.4.8

Comment: This issue is still not resolved, could some one please look into ?